# Fix Source Control Local Path

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

We are using Visual Studio Pro 2012 with Source Control.

One user has the **Local Path** mapped to the network location for the checked in files.

Is there a way to update all of them at once to use her local folder?

Comment: You mean that the mapping is pointing to a share, like \\server\home\thatuser\src, and you want to switch to c:\users\thatuser\src ?

Comment: @GiulioVian - Yes - the mapping for the Local Path is currently pointed to the network location for the checked in files (the Source Location). I want to change it to the local user's folder (which also happens to be on a network drive - \\server\Users\thatuser\docs\VS2012\TFS...).

Comment: You should not map your workspace to a network location.